# Migration HTTP to HTTPS except 1 directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to migrate a site from HTTP to HTTPS except one directory.
It's not working ....  first of all, is it possible to code this?

```
#https exept directory dir2 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dir2[NC] 
RewriteRule^https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dir2[NC]
> ```

You are missing a space delimiter before the *flags* argument, so this will never match the intended directory. It should read:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dir2 [NC]
```

> ```
> RewriteRule^https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
> ```

You are also missing two spaces surrounding the *pattern*. So this will again never match anything. So, this should read:

```
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

*Spaces* are delimiters in Apache config files.

---

However, this can be improved, as you don't need the additional condition if you just want to exclude a single directory. You should use the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule !^dir2 https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. The redirection in https is working but the directory 'dir2'  too. The exception not working. Perhaps with !^/dir2 ?

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache. No, it should not be `!/dir2` - there should be no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ when used in `.htaccess`.

Comment: No, it's the same.

Comment: Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file? If so then please add your  `.htaccess` file to your question.

Comment: The exception not working even with cleaning browser cache. All the site migrate in https. The adress for dir2 is https://mysite/dir2/. And of course, I would like mysite/dir2/. Yes I have rewriting but there working even in https.

Comment: The order of directives is important. Please include the contents of your `.htaccess` file in your question. The above will certainly exclude any requests for the URL-path starting `/dir2`. However, is it possible that your application is redirecting to HTTPS regardless of these directives in `.htacccess`?